# Hadoop multi node configuration: Master node not able to initiate data node in slave

Tags: hadoop, installation

In the below example saturn is the master node and pluto is the slave node.

```
hadoop@saturn:~$ start-dfs.sh
16/02/22 15:51:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [saturn]
hadoop@saturn's password:
saturn: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-saturn.out
hadoop@saturn's password: pluto: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-pluto.out
```

It gets hanged at the last instruction.

I am puzzled as to why it is happening like this.

Update: Earlier i had saturn and pluto both in usr/local/hadoop/slaves file but when i changed it to pluto only then it ran. But now the datanode is not getting initiated in slave/pluto node.

As requested by @running:

Log of /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-pluto.out

ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15838
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15838
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Log of /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-saturn.out

ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1031371
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1031371
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

(I am sorry for the formatting)

Comment: Can you show logs: `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-pluto.out` and `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-saturn.out` ?

Comment: Also the output of jps in saturn:
4522 ResourceManager
3902 SecondaryNameNode
3662 NameNode
4822 Jps



Also the output of jps in pluto:
2672 Jps
2545 NodeManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because the couple of files did not have the required permission to write.
So i did chown and chmod to the /usr/local/ and it worked.